# Flip page animation as in Google Play Books

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

How to create animation as in **"Google Play Books"**, when turning page?
Maybe it's ViewPager.PageTransformer?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOJ15ysPsRo

Comment: found this with a little search https://github.com/Yalantis/FlipViewPager.Draco ... Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I have seen that, but it not what need me. Thx for help.

Comment: try this , think it matches your requiremnt  https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Comment: @NidhinPrathap I saw it too, but if i will be use this library, I can't implement OnClickListener inside SurfaceView for my ImageView or another View.

Comment: @neic did you find a solution?

Comment: @MachoProgrammer, no. For this effect need use OpenGl

Comment: @neic Ok thank you

Comment: @neic this is exactly what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/40723084/3488710

Answer (score 0):

Someone has created exactly the same effect - https://github.com/karacken/PlayLikeCurl (using OpenGL)

Details (from a different answer) -

You have to use OpenGl for making such effect in Android and have to use the below common sinusoidal graph equation :-

y=Asin(2π/λ*x)

Where,

A = Amplitude (i.e. the elevation of curl we want).

λ = Wavelength (i.e. the length of the curl we want).

x = The X axis variable which will change as you move the page.

You have to draw 3 pages on SurfaceView namely 'LeftPage' , 'CenterPage' and 'RightPage', 'CenterPage' is always visible and is responsible for 'right curl' animation while 'LeftPage' is responsible for 'left curl' animation and 'RightPage' just stay static. For detecting gestures use default GestureDetector class.