# Page Transformer animation like Google Play Books app

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer, google-play-books

I want to implement `animation` when change the page in `ViewPager`, I know that I must use `PageTransformer`. I want to create an `animation` as `Play Books` app from google (like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOJ15ysPsRo)).
I had searched a lot but no answer was accepted. 
Any one can help?

Comment: none of them helped you ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40723084/3488710 check this

Answer (score 0):

There are many page curl libraries:

[android-FlipView](https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView)

[transitionviewpager](https://github.com/SalmanJawed/transitionviewpager)

[android-flip](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip)

[FoldableLayout](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/FoldableLayout)

[FoldableLayout2](https://github.com/worldline/FoldableLayout)

[android_page_curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)

I wish one of them fulfill your need

Comment: thank you for your help but they are not what i need :(. If you have time to see the video demo, you will see